# RegEx - String To Help Match

Tags: regex

I read somewhere that it is possible to have a RegEx in which strings preceding and following are not to be matched, but instead help with ambiguities.

For example, I would like a RegEx that matches only "TESTING" from the second line ("defTESTINGghi") and nothing from line one and line two.

```
abcTESTINGdef
defTESTINGghi
ghiTESTINGjkl
```

Comment: [Have you tried anything yourself?](http://regex101.com/r/xY4fO7/1)

Comment: I did try that although it would quickly become very complicated (as I am relatively new to RegEx). Besides, I wrote, "I read somewhere that it is possible to have a RegEx in which strings preceding and following are not to be matched, but instead help with ambiguities". I wanted to know what it was called and how it would look like an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regexes to match the string `TESTING` only on the second line,

- [Through positive lookahead and lookbehind,](http://regex101.com/r/sJ5uO4/1)

  ```
  (?<=def)TESTING(?=ghi)
  ```

  Matches the string TESTING only if it's present just after to the `def` and must be follwed by `ghi`.
- [Through positive lookahead,](http://regex101.com/r/sJ5uO4/3)

  ```
  TESTING(?=ghi)
  ```

  Matches the string `TESTING` only if it's followed by `ghi`.
- [Through negative lookahead,](http://regex101.com/r/sJ5uO4/2)

  ```
  TESTING(?!def|jkl)
  ```

  Matches the string `TESTING` if it's not followed by `def` or `jkl`.

[Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for! (The positive lookahead and lookbehind)

Thanks for helping me out everyone!

Answer (score 2):

If supported you can use the `\K` escape sequence. `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included. The **Positive Lookahead** asserts that the preceded is followed by `ghi`.

```
def\KTESTING(?=ghi)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bR9gA3/4)

Or depending on what your definition of the preceded and following not being matched are, why not simply use a capturing group to capture only the desired subpattern?

```
def(TESTING)ghi
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bR9gA3/2)

Comment: The first part of you answer works, although it is not what I was looking for. I wanted it to match "TESTING" from "defTESTINGghi" but not from "defTESTINGabc". As for the second part of your answer, it would quickly become complicated for me as I am a beginner at RegEx. (See full response to Scrowler)

Comment: @JC Updated, you can use a positive lookahead to assure that `ghi` follows.

Comment: Then which would be the preferred method? "(?<=def)TESTING(?=ghi)" or "def\KTESTING(?=ghi)" ?

Comment: @JC In this case either will be fine.